# Mass-action differential equations for the Ivanova reaction system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chemistry

I have a homework problem in which I'm given an Ivanova reaction system

$$X+Y \longrightarrow 2Y$$

$$Y+Z \longrightarrow 2Z$$

$$Z+X \longrightarrow 2X$$

and I'm asked to write the mass-action ODEs with respective rate constants $k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}$.

This is a course on nonlinear dynamics, and the last time I took chemistry was in high school. Thus, I'm not sure how to write mass-action ODEs given an Ivanova reaction system, whatever that is. I've googled mass-action and Ivanova to try to find how to write the mass-action ODEs, but I'm still confused.

Here is my attempt after searching around on the internet:

$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \frac{dY}{dt} = k_{1}XY$$

$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \frac{dZ}{dt} = k_{2}YZ$$

$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \frac{dX}{dt} = k_{3}XZ$$

If I could get some sort of verification and/or hints that would be much appreciated, and I feel like I can do the rest of what the homework asks.

Comment: Pages 5-7 of this [presentation](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cse510/slides/bio.lec3.pdf) look to give a nice summary of chemical kinetics via ODEs. Based on it, I'd say you've only included the terms which cause concentrations to increase; but those reactions include the conversion of one reactant into another, and that should be reflected in your RHS's.

Comment: I'm still somewhat lost with all the terminology and so forth.

Comment: Page 6 looks to be the key, though it does require some careful reading. I think what it boils down to is 1) the halves on the LHS aren't needed or correct, 2) the term $k_1 X Y$ should reflects the conversion of one $X$ to one $Y$, so it should increase the concentration of $Y$ and decrease that of $X$. So it should appear in both rate equations but with opposite signs. (Notation-wise, note that $X$ is the name of the compound; its concentration is labelled $[X]$, and that's what appears in the rate equations.)

Comment: I once read in a book by Erdi and Toth that the Ivanova system might exhibit periodic solutions. However the statement seemed to suggest that it was not proven and still open at that time. Does anybody know more about that?

Answer (score 1):

The law of mass action says that the rate of reaction is proportional to the concentrations of reagents. This is how you can write your equation for $[X]$, concentration of $X$:
$$
\dot{[X]}=k_3[Z][X]+k_3[Z][X]-k_3[Z][X]-k_1[X][Y],
$$
where two first terms comes from $2X$ expression in one of your reactions, third term comes from $Z+X$ part, and the last term comes from $X+Y$ term in the first reaction. I also assumed that the rate constants are $k_1,k_2,k_3$ from top to bottom. Simplifying, you get
$$
\dot{[X]}=k_3[Z][X]-k_1[X][Y],
$$
and the rest should be easy.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. (By the way, I imagine that parting phrase is only intended as regards _writing down_ the ODEs. Solving them is decidedly different matter.)

Comment: Very illustrative, thank you. However, why is it that $Y+Z$ parts don't play a role in the above equation?

Comment: @boldbrandywine Because these reaction does not involve $X$. You need to write two more equations, for $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: How does it not involve $X$? You obtained that equation from $Z+X \longrightarrow 2X$, right?

Comment: @boldbrandywine I obtained my equation from $X+Y\to 2Y$ and $Z+X\to 2X$. The third reaction $Y+Z\to 2Z$ does not involve $X$ and hence be omitted.

Comment: @artem: Another way to understand the point of contention is that, while $\frac{dX}{dt}$ doesn't care about the reaction $Y+Z\to 2Z$ directly, it would matter in expressing $\frac{d^2 X}{dt^2}$ since this would require differentiating $Y$ and $Z$ wrt to time, and those first derivatives do care about reaction. So that third reaction only matters to $X$ at second-order.